# How to transfer Dark Souls 1 progress to steam?

Tags: steam, dark-souls

Is it possible to transfer Dark Souls 1 progress/profile/charactes to steam?

I used to play in a standalone Dark Souls aplication (PC), but it has problem with online gameplay. I realy love the game and since there is a sale on steam would like to buy it there. But it would be really sad to lose all the progress and startover. I found something like a profile file here

```
c:\Users\ME\Documents\DarkSouls\Player1\DRAKS0005.sl2
```

so I wonder may be I can copy it to a steam darksoul folder and this will work? Or there is any other way to transfer my progress? Has anyone done anything like this with steam games?

Comment: I can say that the save file has the same name under steam. I haven't tried your scenario, I just have the steam copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:
1. Install and run the game from steam.
2. Press "New Game" and create a character and exit.
3. Move the old file:

```
c:\Users\ME\Documents\NBGI\DarkSouls\Player1\DRAKS0005.sl2
```

to replace the steam file, which is:

```
 c:\Users\ME\Documents\NBGI\DarkSouls\DRAKS0005.sl2
```

I played 2 hours with it and everything looks fine: all chars, progress and even settings are transefed.

P.S. I'm not sure whether steps 1 and 2 are obligatory.

Comment: I'd recommend doing steps 1 and 2 as the game may use Cloud saves on Steam... which would overwrite your save with the one in the cloud.

Comment: DS1 does not have cloud saves. I've been playing it on two separate computers (with steam on both) and I've had to email my save file back and forth.